# Python reading a file

Tags: python

I have a file('sample.txt') which consists of all paths of a directory in my system. You  can see few lines of the file below

```
/media/arjith007/Education/$RECYCLE.BIN
/media/arjith007/Education/.Trash-1000
/media/arjith007/Education/output.txt
```

my task is to read all lines in the file('sample.txt') and I should determine whether the given path is a file or directory. The code I'm using is :

```
import os
f = open('sample.txt','r')
for line in f:
    print os.path.isfile(line)
f.close()
```

The error executing is, even for the paths of the files the print statement returns False!!!(I guess the problem  is os.path is not able to take line variable in single quotes)So can anyone help me in correcting the code?

Comment: If your file contains one path per line, then the `line` variable will have newlines on the end. So while `/media/arjith007/Education/output.txt` exists, the file `/media/arjith007/Education/output.txt\n` does not.  Try adding a `line = line.strip()`

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but even  now  it is showing incorrect answer! When I place the paths directly I'm getting the correct answers. But I think os.path.isfile(line) is not able to assume  quotation marks for the variable =line ,so it is returning false

Comment: Which quotation marks do you mean?  The example lines of the file you've shown don't have any.

Comment: Using your file contents, this works for me: https://gist.github.com/srfraser/4e95ead386c1854d0c09eda572854ead

Answer (score 1):

**1) Remove end of line (aka. `\n`)**
If you read line by line, the last char will be the `\n` (which means "newline"). You can remove it with:

`path = line[:-1] # take every character of 'line' except the last one`

*or if you want a safer solution:*

```
def remove_newline(str):
    return str.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')

path = remove_newline(line)
```

This will remove `\r` as well, which are used of some systems. (more information: [Newline, wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline))

**2) Check `path` types**
Python gives you two functions: from `os.path`([doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html)) namely:

```
os.path.isfile(path) 
os.path.isdir(path)
```

**3) So it should looks like:**

```
import os
f = open('sample.txt','r')

for line in f:
    path = remove_newline(line)

    if os.path.isdir(path):
        print("Its a directory!")

    elif os.path.isfile(path):
        print("Its a regular file!")

    else:
        print("Hmmm it looks like its not a correct path!")

f.close()
```

Hope it helps
`pltrdy`

Answer (score -1):

Try jumping to that path, if an error occurs then it is not a path.
also, using .strip("\n") may also remove other parts of the path apart from the newline character

```
import os
f = open("sample.txt","r")
for line in f:
    try:
        path = line[0:len(line)-1] #removes the '\n' character
        os.chdir(path)
        print(True)
    except: #when it tries to change it's directory to something invalid
        print(False)
f.close()
```

Comment: You should use `line[:-1]` to remove the last character here

Answer (score -1):

If you print each line within delimiting characters (such as `<>`), you will see that your line read in `for line in f` ends with the new line character (`\n`). Additionally, you can compare the line before and after stripping to debug whether it needs stripping:

```
import os

f = open('sandbox.txt','r')

lineNo = 0

for line in f:
    lineNo += 1
    lineStripped = line.strip()

    print("Line %d before stripping: <%s>" % (lineNo, line))
    print("Line %d after stripping: <%s>" % (lineNo, lineStripped))

    needStrip = (line != lineStripped)

    print("Line %d needs stripping: %s" % (lineNo, needStrip))

    isFile = os.path.isfile(lineStripped)

    print("Line %d is file: %s" % (lineNo, isFile))
f.close()
```

for me outputs:

```
Line 1 before stripping: </media/arjith007/Education/$RECYCLE.BIN
>
Line 1 after stripping: </media/arjith007/Education/$RECYCLE.BIN>
Line 1 needs stripping: True
Line 1 is file: False
Line 2 before stripping: </media/arjith007/Education/.Trash-1000
>
Line 2 after stripping: </media/arjith007/Education/.Trash-1000>
Line 2 needs stripping: True
Line 2 is file: False
Line 3 before stripping: </media/arjith007/Education/output.txt>
Line 3 after stripping: </media/arjith007/Education/output.txt>
Line 3 needs stripping: False
Line 3 is file: False
```

Having the closing tag (`>`) on the next line when printing the value before stripping indicates that the line is read with its trailing new line.